# Validate TextBox input at caret location

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox, decimal

I've got the following code to format decimal input into a `TextBox`.

```
If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse e.KeyChar = "."c Then
     If e.KeyChar = "."c Then
        If txtPrice.Text.Contains("."c) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
     ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
         If txtPrice.Text.Contains("."c) Then
             Dim value As String = txtPrice.Text
             Dim units As String = value.Substring(value.IndexOf("."c) + 1)

          If units.Length >= 2 Then
             e.Handled = True
          End If
      End If
   End If
ElseIf e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then 
   e.Handled = True
End If
```

This all works fine, however, if I enter a value into the `TextBox`, e.g. 10.50 , when I then try to just delete the first 0 and change the value to 11.50, it won't allow me to, as there are 2 digits after the decimal point which cancels all other user input, to ensure that only 2 decimal places can be entered.

Is there a way that I can validate this to check if the digit is being added before or after the decimal point? Or if it can check it based on the caret location?

There is probably an easier way to validate decimal in a `TestBox`, however this code is also used for validating grids and other controls, so something in this format is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `SelectionStart` property.

```
If units.Length >= 2 AndAlso txtPrice.SelectionStart > txtPrice.Text.IndexOf(".") Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Above code explained:

If text already 2 characters after the `.` you're trying to add another, prevent keypress. If adding before the `.` then allow.